# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<<' token

Tags: c++

On Compiling follow programs using g++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

cout<<"Before Main"<<endl;

int main()
{
cout<<"Within Main"<<endl;
}
```

Errors: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<<' token.
So may i know how to fixe this.
What's the reason for getting erros.

Comment: [Decent C++ books. Buy them.](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute statements outside a function.

Comment: A declaration is a statement. It is executed (e.g., function calls in initializer are executed). So, *literally* your statement is incorrect. But I see what you're trying to express. Unfortunately, the C++ standard does not, AFAIK, give us terms to talk about that! :-(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put non-declaration statements at namespace scope.

However, an expression statement can be converted to a declaration, e.g.

```
bool const bah = (cout<<"Before Main"<<endl);
```

It is generally not a good idea, but perhaps worth knowing about?

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

Such statements cannot be executed without putting it inside a function body. If you want something before `main()`, then encapsulate it in a global struct and define an object.

```
struct Print {
  Print() { cout<<"Before Main"<<endl; }
  ~Print() { cout<<"After Main"<<endl; }
} print;                        // <--- declare/define object

int main()
{
  cout<<"Within Main"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal, everything what will be execute must be inside main function. Of course you can write second function, and there put `cout<<"Before Main"<<endl;`, but main will be execute firstly.
you can write :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void f() {
   cout<<"Before Main"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   f();
   cout<<"Within Main"<<endl;
}
```

But main is first function which will be executed.

Comment: (a) It's `void`; (b) "everything [to be executed] must be inside [the] main function" is misleading; (c) "method" is not well-defined in C++, and even outside of C++ it usually means "member function", but it is not a member function here.